# How to Allow NULL Foreign Keys with SQLite-net-extensions

Tags: sqlite-net

I'm trying to add a nullable foreign key mapping but it doesn't work. I know the database allows nulls, since I can insert a new record with a null foreign key when using Datagrip. I only get the error when trying to insert from a Xamarin.Forms project building for Android(SQLite.SQLiteException: 'Constraint')
My classes look like:

```
 public class Item
  {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Location))]   
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    [ManyToOne] 
    public Location Location { get; set; }
  }
  public class Location
  {    
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    [OneToMany]  
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
  }
```

And my inserts like

```
//This will no work
var todoItem = new Item()
{
  Name = "Test item " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(),
  Description = "Desc",
  Location = null  // I tried with and without this line
};
await App.Database.SaveItemAsync(todoItem);

//This will work
var todoItem = new Item()
{
  Name = "Test item " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(),
  Description = "Desc",
  LocationId = 1
};
await App.Database.SaveItemAsync(todoItem);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: If you manually try to execute an insert, is it successful?

Comment: Yes, I added a row with DataGrip tool, and it just inserted a null value on the LocationId column. I used both, the UI grid and the console tools from DataGrip - insert into Item(name) values("test") -, both were succesful

Comment: Apparently if it's null, it's not generated into the query under the hood. Can you alter your table to make sure that the column defaults to null?

Comment: @LajosArpad It didn't work, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the library needs that the id field to be nullable, so instead of

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(Location))]  
public int LocationId { get; set; }
```

I should use

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(Location))]  
public int? LocationId { get; set; }
```

PS: In my case just building the project didn't took the changes on to effect, I only could see the result after Rebuild the project..(I'm new with Xamarin, probably I have something misconfigured...I hope)